# Firebird statements no error but no result

Tags: python, sql, firebird, flamerobin

Running Firebird on my Raspberry Pi at the moment and using FlameRobin to control it. With another Raspberry Pi I want to some statements to it, I don't get any error codes but the data just doesn't get there.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='10.100.2.197/3050:/home/trainee2/Desktop/ice', user='sysdba', password='trainee')

text_file = open("namen1.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
namen = lines
text_file.close()
status = [0] * 12
indexSpatie = 0

pinnen = [18,23,24,25,20,21,17,27,6,13,19,26]
controlepin = [1] * 12
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
for p in range(0,12):
    GPIO.setup(pinnen[p],GPIO.IN)
    print pinnen[p]

cur = con.cursor()

while True:
for e in range(0,12):
    status[e] = GPIO.input(pinnen[e])
    if (status[e] != controlepin[e]):
        n = e

        naam = str(namen[n])
        indexSpatie = naam.index(' ')
        voornaam = naam[:indexSpatie]
        achternaam = naam[indexSpatie:]
        stat = str(status[n])
        datum = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

        print( voornaam + achternaam  + " met pinnummer: " + str(pinnen[n]) + " heeft status van " + stat + " op vandaag: " + datum)
        cur.execute("insert into ICEDATA (PRENAME, NAME, DATUM) values(?,?,?)",(voornaam,achternaam,datum))
        controlepin[e] = status[e]
time.sleep(1)
```

I post the whole code cause I don't see anything wrong with the statement and connection itself.

Comment: I don't see a commit statement there - try to add `cur.Commit()` or some such into the end of your script (I'm not familiar with the python driver so don't know the exact method).

Answer (score 1):

Like @ain said, forgot the commit statement on the connection

```
    con.commit()
```